# Line L intersects with new line that passes through point P (intersection is 4 units away from point Q)?

Tags: vectors, parametric

Looking for tips with regard to this problem.

Let $L$ be the line with parametric equations

$$\left\{\begin{align}
x &= 1−2t\\
y &= 4−t\\
z &= 5+t
\end{align}\right.$$
Find the vector equation for a line that passes through the point $P(−5, −4, 1)$ and intersects $L$ at a point that is exactly $4$ units from the point $Q(1, 4, 5)$. Note that there are two possible correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of intersection is somewhere on the line $L$, where each point $(x,y,z)$ can be represented by the parametric equations $A(1-2t,4-t,5+t)$.  We know that $|\vec{QA}|=4$, so we have
\begin{align}
4&=\sqrt{(1-2t-1)^2+(4-t-4)^2+(5+t-5)^2}\\
16&=(2t)^2+(-t)^2+(t)^2\\
16&=6t^2\\
t&=\pm\frac4{\sqrt6}
\end{align}

All we need now is to substitute $t$ into point $A$, then write a vector equation of a line that passes through $A$ and $P$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi! Yes I was able to work with that and come up with the answer for the line that passes through A and P. For anyone who is wondering, the following is the answer for the question.

[x y z] = [-10 4 -7] + t [(-6√11 - 3√2)/√11) , (-5√11 - 2√2)/√11, (3√11-3√2)/√11]